# How can I access a Mantis Bug Tracker from Android?

Tags: applications

We track our bugs on Mantis, and I was hoping to find an Android App for it, since it exposes a PHP-SOAP API ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939794/mantis-bug-tracker-api-integration)) which Eclipse uses.

Does anyone know of existing apps (or projects) for accessing a Mantis Bug Tracker from Android devices? I would be happy to contribute patches too, if needed.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: This is my product, but since this answers the exact question, I am posting the link. The Android app for mantis is available and can be downloaded from - https://market.android.com/details?id=greatdevelopers.mantis

Answer (score 3):

I have a Android app for Mantis Bug Tracker ready. I'll be releasing it soon. In case you want to have a preview, do send me a message. Soon I'll be posting an URL for android market.

UPDATE: The android app for mantis has been released and can be downloaded from - https://market.android.com/details?id=greatdevelopers.mantis

DISCLAIMER: I am not advertising my app. I am just informing you that something like that is available. For more details contact me. In case the community feels this is not correct, I'll

Comment: Please see [this post on meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/584/do-you-want-to-beta-test-do-you-need-beta-testers) about getting beta testers from the Android Enthusiasts community.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use mantisconnect. It has got a java client as well. More info can be had on here:

http://www.futureware.biz/mantisconnect/downloads.php

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mantisconnect/files/Java%20Client%20API/1.1.1.1/

Comment: Although Android apps are normally written in Java, the OS itself won't run Java apps or applets, they need to be recompiled into "Dalvik" using an Android development environment. So the Mantis Connect Java Client won't work on Android as it is, but as it appears to be open source it could be modified to use the Android API and recompiled by someone and released as an Android app. See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/987/java-applet-inside-browser-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout MantisTouch which provides an interface that is designed from the ground up for mobile devices including Android, iOS and Windows Phone.  You can use MantisTouch via the proxy at http://mantisbt.mobi or you can install on your owner server.  The advantage of MantisTouch is the it works across a wide variety of devices and its license covers all users associated with your MantisBT instance including your team and your customers.  Rather than having to buy an app per user.

For more details checkout http://www.mantisbt.org/mantistouch.php