# Is there a web browser+Java plugin available for Android?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any Android browsers that support loading a Java Applet in-browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/987/are-there-any-android-browsers-that-support-loading-a-java-applet-in-browser)

I am having some issues accessing internet banking etc on my tablet with Android as the operating system. Is there any way of avoiding this, or solutions so that i can access webpages that rely on Java?

Answer (score 0):

I've never even heard of a java browser plug in for Android, and I'm quite surprised to hear of a financial institution using java as an integral part of their website.  I do believe you're hosed for that particular issue.