# enabling java for Lenovo ThinkPad tablet?

Tags: browser, java, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any Android browsers that support loading a Java Applet in-browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/987/are-there-any-android-browsers-that-support-loading-a-java-applet-in-browser)

I am new to the tablet world. I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Tablet and I am having trouble on some websites when using the browser that you access through the world icon on the home page. I get a message that says that I have a browser problem and that java support has been turned off. I can't find where to turn this on or download if I need. I am sure this is a simple user error on my part. can someone please help me? I am able to find directions on how to fix this on safari, internet explore etc, but again I am ignorant and not figuring out if I am actually using one of thesesince the icon doesn't match..Please take pity on this naive newbie and help me!
thanks
Ss